# Setting to turn off viewing of Facebook photos from those tagged as "Public"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-photos, facebook-privacy

Currently, to someone that views my timeline as `Public`, they are able to see all my photos. I've been looking at my Account and Privacy settings, but no where is there a change that allows me to turn off all photos from being viewed as Public. This is a bit disconcerting to me, as that opens up a lot of people being able to see my photos, regardless of their affiliation to me.

Is there a setting that allows me to turn off all Public access to my photos, and only my Friends can view these photos?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go into your [Privacy Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy). Under "Who can see my stuff?" there's an option to "Limit past posts". Choosing that option should take everything you've previously shared to "Public" or "Friends of Friends" to simply "Friends".

You'll also, of course, want to make sure your setting for future posts to something more restrictive.

Comment: I did just this, but when I went to "View as: Public", I was still able to see my old photos. With that said, it seems limiting old posts, in conjunction with going to some settings page which allows me manually change from "public" to "friends", I was able to entirely remove my profile from public. Now even if you are given a direct link to my profile, you cannot see it.